# css pseudo class not showing or hovering

Tags: css, class, hover, pseudo-class

I have a div in a div, what I'm trying to do is have it so when you hover on the parent the child changes.  The problem is I can't get anything to show up, I'm not sure why.

css:

```
#3d_stack {
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-49px, 55px);
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-perspective: 50;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

#3d_stack > div:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  height: 34px;
  width: 46px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .3;
}

#3d_stack:hover > div:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  height: 34px;
  width: 46px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="3d_stack">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I have a fiddle set up here  http://jsfiddle.net/4p8CM/223/

Comment: You shouldn't start element id's and classes with digits. That's probably why nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe id's can start with numbers I have removed the `3` from the start of the div id in the HTML and the css and your `div`'s are showing.

Answer (score 0):

ID's and classes can't start with numbers or symbols. only on some browsers but what's the point. To add (For reference) also don't make your elements (classes & ID's) too short (like 2 character) as JavaScript will have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody here didn't make another, repaired snippet, so I did (removed number from first place of ID property).

Also, as I can see, you used `webkit` vendor prefixing - you should consider prefixing another vendors too (I don't know which browser you use). I have found a great [tool](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) online with which I did prefixing for you, too.

Without going in details, I can see that your `transform` can move the container outside of view, so maybe that can cause some visibility problems too (you can see in code snippet that it is almost outside of view).

```css
#d_stack {
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-49px, 55px);
          transform: translate(-49px, 55px);
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
          perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-perspective: 50;
          perspective: 50;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

#d_stack > div:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
          transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  height: 34px;
  width: 46px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .3;
}

#d_stack:hover > div:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
          transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  height: 34px;
  width: 46px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div id="d_stack">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of id, use class. i.e.

```
<div class="box1"></div>
// css
div.box1{
}
```